# mod_evasive Not Available in EPEL Repo For Centos 5?

Tags: apache-2.2

I am setting up a new VPS running 64-bit vers Centos 5.11 .  I was able to add the EPEL repository and download the epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm package.  After this I was able to install the mod_security package for Apache, but not mod_evasive.  When trying to install, I got a 0 packages installed message.  I used the following command to search for mod_evasive:  yum list mod_e* and mod_evasive wasn't available anywhere in the list.

Does this mean that the mod_evasive package isn't available in the repo I am using, and if so, which repo should I be using?

UPDATE:  ok, after some poking around it appears that mod_evasive is indeed not in EPEL 5:  https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/mod_evasive/

I also noticed that mod_reqtimeout isn't there, either.

Comment: A new VPS running CentOS 5 is probably not what you should want, CentOS 7 is the current release. Second the epel release should match your CentOS release...

Comment: EL5 is in [Production 3 phase](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata). New projects should not be started on it, and planning should be in progress to migrate existing projects before support ends.

Comment: Thanks to both @HBruijn and Michael Hampton.  I don't have the option of installing CentOs 7.  My options outside oif Centos 5 are  cent OS 6 (32 bit or 64 bit), centos-6-x86_64, or centos-6.2-purple1.8.8-piaf_2.0.6.2-5-64bit.  Which option is best?